# Access VBA: Change visibility of header or footer on a form clears selections in listbox object

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem with a MS Access (MSO 365 x64 v2004) form. In the detail section of the form I have a listbox with multiple selections enabled. The form has a footer ("frmOptions") which is hidden by default.
When having selected multiple items in the listbox and unhiding the footer (frmOptions.visible=true), all selections are cleared for some reason. This only occurs when setting the visibility of the footer to true.. Hiding the form footer does not seem to have any effect on the listbox selections. Off course I can write a function where the selections are restored again, but this should not be necessary. The listbox has no Beforeupdate/Afterupdate routine. The code to hide/unhide the footer is this:

```
Private Sub btn_options_Click()
    If Me.frmOptions.Visible Then
        Me.frmOptions.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.frmOptions.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there something I have to consider in this code, maybe a setting of the listbox or form footer to prevent the unwanted de-selection in the listbox?

Thx for your help!

Art.

Comment: Seems that the visibility of `frmOptions` depends on count of items selected in listbox. So, `SelecttedItemCount = ...'count of selected items in ListBox
Me.frmOptions.Visible = SelectedItemsCount>0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for your replies! Too bad that this may be by design. I now solved this based on the following change in the form code and new function. Any improvements on the code are as always very welcome)

Changed procedure in the form code:

```
Private Sub btn_options_Click()
    Dim varSelItems() As Variant
    varSelItems = ListBoxItems(Me, "customer_contact_cat") 'Save the listbox selections
    Me.frmOptions.Visible = Not Me.frmOptions.Visible
    Call ListBoxItems(Me, "customer_contact_cat", varSelItems) 'Restore the listbox Selections
End Sub
```

Added function in a module so it may be reused in other forms:

```
Public Function ListBoxItems(frmName As Form, strLbName As String, Optional varSelItems As Variant) As Variant

    Dim lngA As Long
    Dim lngB As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim varItems() As Variant
    
    Set ctl = frmName.Controls(strLbName)
    
    If Not IsArray(varSelItems) Then
        ReDim varItems(ctl.ItemsSelected.Count)
        lngA = 0
        For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
            varItems(lngA) = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
            lngA = lngA + 1
        Next varItem
        ListBoxItems = varItems()
    Else
        For lngA = 0 To UBound(varSelItems) - 1
            For lngB = 0 To ctl.ListCount - 1
                If ctl.ItemData(lngB) = varSelItems(lngA) Then
                    ctl.Selected(lngB) = True
                End If
            Next lngB
        Next lngA
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code can be reduced to:

```vb
Private Sub btn_options_Click()

    Me.frmOptions.Visible = Not Me.frmOptions.Visible

End Sub
```

Next, I can reproduce this, but can't tell why. Will try to find an explanation.

Most likely, this is by design for some reason and will not be changed in the near future, perhaps never. So you can just as well start programming the reselection of the listbox items.

Comment: The reason for the issue is, that turning on the form footer is causing Access to recalculate what is visible on the screen, and in that process, it will destroy and recreate the listbox, and since the selection state isn't saved, it can’t be restored. You shouldn't expect this behaviour to change, so your work-around posted is currently the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also can reproduce the behaviour and also think you would have to accept that.

A workaround is to resize the footer instead of hiding it.

Add a class variable `mFooterHeight` to the form and store the footers height during opening the form there.

```vb
Private mFrmOptionsInitialHeight As Long

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    mFrmOptionsInitialHeight = Me.frmOptions.Height
End Sub
```

Then you can toggle the size of the footer with this line of code:

```vb
  Me.frmOptions.Height = IIf(Me.frmOptions.Height = 0, mFrmOptionsInitialHeight, 0)
```

Comment: Thx, but thus will not work. I already use a code to set a form location, height and width (because Access sucks in this). The footer (or header) cannot be set to 0 if there are controls placed in this section unless you want to set these controls to 0 (dimensions and location) as well. That would require lots of coding.